# Pylint error: 'optparse.OptionValueError: option spelling-dict: invalid value: 'en_US', should be in ['']'

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10, command-line-interface, locale, pylint

When running anything related to the `pylint` - command in the `MINGW64-bash-CLI on Windows 10`, be it e.g.

```
pylint src/packages/ics/plugins/
```

or just to know the version

```
pylint -version
```

I always get the same error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.9.4\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\username\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.9.4\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\username\Projects\proj-venv\Scripts\pylint.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\username\projects\proj-venv\lib\site-packages\pylint\__init__.py", line 24, in run_pylint
    PylintRun(sys.argv[1:])
  File "c:\users\username\projects\proj-venv\lib\site-packages\pylint\lint\run.py", line 333, in __init__
    linter.load_config_file()
  File "c:\users\username\projects\proj-venv\lib\site-packages\pylint\config\option_manager_mixin.py", line 315, in load_config_file
    self.global_set_option(option, value)
  File "c:\users\username\projects\proj-venv\lib\site-packages\pylint\config\option_manager_mixin.py", line 186, in global_set_option
    self._all_options[opt].set_option(opt, value)
  File "c:\users\username\projects\proj-venv\lib\site-packages\pylint\config\options_provider_mixin.py", line 54, in set_option
    value = _validate(value, optdict, optname)
  File "c:\users\username\projects\proj-venv\lib\site-packages\pylint\config\option.py", line 115, in _validate
    return _call_validator(_type, optdict, name, value)
  File "c:\users\username\projects\proj-venv\lib\site-packages\pylint\config\option.py", line 96, in _call_validator
    return VALIDATORS[opttype](optdict, option, value)
  File "c:\users\username\projects\proj-venv\lib\site-packages\pylint\config\option.py", line 83, in <lambda>
    "choice": lambda opt, name, value: _choice_validator(opt["choices"], name, value),
  File "c:\users\username\projects\proj-venv\lib\site-packages\pylint\config\option.py", line 31, in _choice_validator
    raise optparse.OptionValueError(msg % (name, value, choices))
optparse.OptionValueError: option spelling-dict: invalid value: 'en_US', should be in ['']
```

It seems that the error is related to the system-locale **'en_US'**.

---

**PS: tried to upgrade pylint to its latest version as suggested**

It still fails with the same error:

```
$ pip install pylint -U
Requirement already satisfied: pylint in c:\users\andreas.luckert\projects\proj-venv\lib\site-packages (2.9.0)
Collecting pylint
  Downloading pylint-2.11.1-py3-none-any.whl (392 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 392 kB 6.4 MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: toml>=0.7.1 in c:\users\andreas.luckert\projects\proj-venv\lib\site-packages (from pylint) (0.10.2)
Collecting astroid<2.9,>=2.8.0
  Downloading astroid-2.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (242 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 242 kB 6.4 MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: mccabe<0.7,>=0.6 in c:\users\andreas.luckert\projects\proj-venv\lib\site-packages (from pylint) (0.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: isort<6,>=4.2.5 in c:\users\andreas.luckert\projects\proj-venv\lib\site-packages (from pylint) (5.9.1)
Collecting typing-extensions>=3.10.0
  Downloading typing_extensions-3.10.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama in c:\users\andreas.luckert\projects\proj-venv\lib\site-packages (from pylint) (0.4.4)
Collecting platformdirs>=2.2.0
  Downloading platformdirs-2.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=20.0 in c:\users\andreas.luckert\projects\proj-venv\lib\site-packages (from astroid<2.9,>=2.8.0->pylint) (49.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: lazy-object-proxy>=1.4.0 in c:\users\andreas.luckert\projects\proj-venv\lib\site-packages (from astroid<2.9,>=2.8.0->pylint) (1.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wrapt<1.13,>=1.11 in c:\users\andreas.luckert\projects\proj-venv\lib\site-packages (from astroid<2.9,>=2.8.0->pylint) (1.12.1)
Installing collected packages: typing-extensions, platformdirs, astroid, pylint
  Attempting uninstall: typing-extensions
    Found existing installation: typing-extensions 3.7.4.3
    Uninstalling typing-extensions-3.7.4.3:
      Successfully uninstalled typing-extensions-3.7.4.3
  Attempting uninstall: astroid
    Found existing installation: astroid 2.6.3.dev0
    Uninstalling astroid-2.6.3.dev0:
      Successfully uninstalled astroid-2.6.3.dev0
  Attempting uninstall: pylint
    Found existing installation: pylint 2.9.0
    Uninstalling pylint-2.9.0:
      Successfully uninstalled pylint-2.9.0
Successfully installed astroid-2.8.0 platformdirs-2.4.0 pylint-2.11.1 typing-extensions-3.10.0.2


$ pylint --version
PYLINTHOME is now 'C:\Users\andreas.luckert\AppData\Local\pylint\pylint\Cache' but obsolescent 'C:\Users\andreas.luckert\.pylint.d' is found; you can safely remove the latter
pylint 2.11.1
astroid 2.8.0
Python 3.9.4 (tags/v3.9.4:1f2e308, Apr  6 2021, 13:40:21) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)]


$ pylint src/packages/ics/plugins/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\andreas.luckert\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.9.4\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\andreas.luckert\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.9.4\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\andreas.luckert\Projects\proj-venv\Scripts\pylint.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\users\andreas.luckert\projects\proj-venv\lib\site-packages\pylint\__init__.py", line 24, in run_pylint
    PylintRun(sys.argv[1:])
  File "C:\users\andreas.luckert\projects\proj-venv\lib\site-packages\pylint\lint\run.py", line 324, in __init__
    linter.load_config_file()
  File "C:\users\andreas.luckert\projects\proj-venv\lib\site-packages\pylint\config\option_manager_mixin.py", line 321, in load_config_file     
    self.global_set_option(option, value)
  File "C:\users\andreas.luckert\projects\proj-venv\lib\site-packages\pylint\config\option_manager_mixin.py", line 189, in global_set_option    
    self._all_options[opt].set_option(opt, value)
  File "C:\users\andreas.luckert\projects\proj-venv\lib\site-packages\pylint\config\options_provider_mixin.py", line 54, in set_option
    value = _validate(value, optdict, optname)
  File "C:\users\andreas.luckert\projects\proj-venv\lib\site-packages\pylint\config\option.py", line 115, in _validate
    return _call_validator(_type, optdict, name, value)
  File "C:\users\andreas.luckert\projects\proj-venv\lib\site-packages\pylint\config\option.py", line 96, in _call_validator
    return VALIDATORS[opttype](optdict, option, value)
  File "C:\users\andreas.luckert\projects\proj-venv\lib\site-packages\pylint\config\option.py", line 83, in <lambda>
    "choice": lambda opt, name, value: _choice_validator(opt["choices"], name, value),
  File "C:\users\andreas.luckert\projects\proj-venv\lib\site-packages\pylint\config\option.py", line 31, in _choice_validator
    raise optparse.OptionValueError(msg % (name, value, choices))
optparse.OptionValueError: option spelling-dict: invalid value: 'en_US', should be in ['']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution can be found in all detail [here](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/5092).

**In short:**

```
pip install pyenchant
```

resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a pylint maintainer. Can you upgrade to the latest pylint with `pip install pylint -U` and check that the problem still exists ? If it does this is definitely a problem with pylint. You can open an issue in [pylint issue tracker](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues) so it gets fixed.

Comment: I tried what you suggested (see PS in my OP), unfortunately with no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by `brew install enchant`

Answer (score 0):

For MacOS users with an Apple Silicon Chip there's a solution on their website, by running following commands:

```
arch -x86_64 /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
arch -x86_64 /usr/local/bin/brew install enchant
```

and then setting the environment variable:

```
export PYENCHANT_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/homebrew/lib/libenchant-2.2.dylib
```

It will install a lot, so it'll take a while.

https://pyenchant.github.io/pyenchant/install.html#apple-silicon-related-errors